# Oracle date equivalent in Postgres

Tags: oracle, postgresql, timestamp

I am trying to use the Postgres import functionality, but it gives me an error on the date datatype.

I have dates in the following format `17-MAY-90 12.00.00.000000000 AM` in my Oracle db, but I need to import the data into my Postgres db. I tried timestap with and without timezone and it still gives me an error msg.

What datatype can I use?

PS: Error I am getting

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: I wasn't using a statement. I was using the import functionality, by right clicking on the table ans selecting 'import'

Comment: Postgres has no "import functionality" - which tool are you using and what is the **exact** error message you got

Comment: In your Oracle database, what is the data type of your date columns?

Comment: Oracle  just say data type 'date'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by going to SQL Developer and under

> Tools-Preferences-Database-Advanced-NLS

and changed the date format to the format I wanted. This way when I exported the file, it exports with the format I want to use and import in my Postgres db.